# Live555 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, live555

I am trying to compile Live555 test programs in Visual Studio 2010, but I wasn't able to do so.

I compiled the libraries without any problems

> BasicUsageEnvironment.lib
>     groupsock.lib
>     liveMedia.lib
>     UsageEnvironment.lib

but when it comes to the test programs, I just couldn't get anywhere. Here is the compiler message when I compile files in the `mediaServer`.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned int)" (??2@YAPAXI@Z)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___security_cookie
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___CxxFrameHandler3
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol @__security_check_cookie@4
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "const type_info::`vftable'" (??_7type_info@@6B@)
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall Medium::isSource(void)const " (?isSource@Medium@@UBE_NXZ)
<more errors>
```

Complete dump here: http://pastebin.com/4bVQAcdp

---

**Update**

I failed to build the project earlier because I unchecked the "Precompiled header" option when creating projects for all the libraries. When linking the libraries to my mediaServer project, VS was unable to resolve all the functions.

I was able to make it work by rebuilding them with "Precompiled header" option checked, and add `#include "stdafx.h"` to each and every *.cpp file.

Afterthought: I have a feeling that I only need to turn on "Precompiled header" option for the mediaServer project. Let me know if you have tried and succeeded. ;-)

---

**Update 2**

Nope. I had to turn on Precompiled Header for each and every one of the static library projects. And add `#include "stdafx.h"` to ~200 *.cpp files. Yep.

Comment: Looks like it is not linking in the *.lib you build. And the `delete` missing looks like something is wrong with the runtime library settings, either mismatched use, added RTC checks etc.

Comment: Is there something that I've missed? The instructions seem rather straightforward here: http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2012-January/014476.html

Comment: Those instructions are vague "I added it all and it worked" reads like they got lucky opposed to what all the settings should be. Are those all static libraries or import libraries for a dll? If for dlls, are the functions being exported and imported properly. Are you consistently using the same runtime library flags (`/MT` vs. `/MD`), are your "runtime security checks" the same across the projects? Character sets etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Update*** 
I took a look at your full dump:

```
1>UsageEnvironment.lib(HashTable.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl operator delete(void *)" (??3@YAXPAX@Z)
```

Based on this first error, what ever source you compiled for your UsageEnviroment Lib, has a reference to a delete operator function. My guess is that either you don't have the correct source code you altered it. Can paste the UsageEnvironment.hh file contents?

---

I happened to be working on building this right now, I just got it working this morning, and per your request I compiled the Test Program "mediaServer". We are operating on a few assumptions here, we are assuming that you built the static libraries correctly.

Assuming the static libraries are correct this is the solution your looking for:

**Include:**

```
c:\Live555\BasicUsageEnvironment\include
c:\Live555\liveMedia\include
c:\Live555\UsageEnvironment\include;
c:\Live555\groupsock\include
$(IncludePath)
```

**Lib Paths:**

```
"*Insert path to your lib files here*";
$(LibraryPath)
```

**Linker input:**

```
Ws2_32.lib 
groupsock.lib
BasicUsageEnvironment.lib
liveMedia.lib
UsageEnvironment.lib
libBasicUsageEnvironment.lib
libgroupsock.lib
```

**Your solution folder should look like this:** 
Make sure the files in Bold are there.

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

**your Source Folder should have the following files:**

mediaServer:

```
**DynamicRTSPServer.cpp**
**DynamicRTSPServer.hh**
**live555MediaServer.cpp**
mediaServer.vcxproj
mediaServer.vcxproj.filters
ReadMe.txt
**rtcp_from_spec.c**
**rtcp_from_spec.h**
stdafx.cpp
stdafx.h
targetver.h
**version.hh**
```

[image]
Based on your errors its looks like you have incorrect source files included in your project, those unresolved reference don't appear anywhere in the live555 project tar file. 
http://live555.com/liveMedia/public/live555-latest.tar.gz

**If this solution doesn't work, please provide screen shots of your project settings for the following tabs:**
include directories
Linker Input
File listing for your project folder.

Let me know if this helps, if this doesn't work we will have to look into how your static libraries were built. We need to see where in your code, those external references are being made, and what ever is making those references need to be excluded as they don't appear in the live555 archive referenced in the link below.